# Susy counts column width and gutters wrong

Tags: math, layout, sass, grid, susy

My susy layout is wrong by 1 pixel and I don't know why:

```
$susy: (
  columns: 12,
  container: 1546px,
  gutter: 26px,
  column-width: 105px,
  global-box-sizing: border-box
);
```

It returns 104px width columns with 27px gutters, the container is as set. Any pointers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few issues here:

- The `gutters` setting (plural) takes a ratio, rather than a length. To get your proper ratio based on the length, you can use division: `gutters: 26px/105px`
- By default, Susy output is in relative `%`, even if you define the grid using `px`. If you want Susy to output exact px-lengths, you should add `math: static` to your settings. In that case, you should also remove your container size, and let Susy calculate that for you based on columns and gutters.

Comment: Thanks! Fixing typo fixed everything!